# Mobile text inputs reload the page on “focus”

Tags: web, mobile, responsive-design

I have a site with form fields that work well on desktop, the problem comes in mobile view. When I click on the form  fields the page reloads, What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look for the culprit javascript code that may be reloading you're page when the screen resizes.

Answer (score 0):

It appears I had a script that automatically reloaded pages on screen resize, so if you experience such a problem, use developer tools to know what script is affecting the said page, go through it to find the culprit.

Regards.